Does VSync behave differently from FreeSync if my FPS exceeds my monitor’s refresh rate?
I am currently playing Doom Eternal and my frame rate usually hovers around 30% above my monitor's max. refresh rate. If it ever drops below, dynamic resolution scaling will immediately bring it back to the max. refresh rate. So I consider myself playing at or above the max. refresh rate.
In my mind, if I turn on either FreeSync or VSync, both will cause every frame to have the same constant input delay and I should theoretically have constant frame pacing, correct? The only way to further reduce input delay at this settings would be to completely turn VSync/FreeSync off and accept tearing. Did I get that right?
